# Flutter : Auto refresh to update the data

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a cart page which contains + and - buttons, on pressing it , the value in the backend changes, but it doesn't automatically change in the frontend.

Cartpage.dart

```
class CartUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const CartUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CartUI> createState() => _CartUIState();
}

class _CartUIState extends State<CartUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Column(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('myOrders')
                      .doc(user?.uid)
                      .collection('items')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Lottie.asset('assets/animations/delivery.json'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                            snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                            return Container(
                              height: 120,
                              width: 300,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 200,
                                        child: Text(
                                          documentSnapshot['name'],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        documentSnapshot['quantity'].toString(),
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Rs.${documentSnapshot['price'].toString()}',
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              width: 40,
                                            ),
                                            ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                if (documentSnapshot['value'] != 0.0) {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    String id = documentSnapshot['docid'];
                                                    final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context, listen: false);
                                                    var postDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myOrders').doc(user?.uid).collection('items').doc();
                                                    Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false).updatecartdata(
                                                        context,
                                                        {
                                                          'value': documentSnapshot['value'] - 0.5,
                                                          'price': documentSnapshot['price'] - (documentSnapshot['ogprice'] / 2),
                                                        },id
                                                    );
                                                  }
                                                  );
                                                }
                                                if (documentSnapshot['value'] ==
                                                    0.5) {
                                                  String id =
                                                  documentSnapshot['docid'];
                                                  Provider.of<ManageData>(
                                                      context,
                                                      listen: false)
                                                      .deleteData(context, id);
                                                }
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('-'),
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                                            Text(documentSnapshot['value']
                                                .toString()),
                                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                                            ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                String id =
                                                documentSnapshot['docid'];
                                                final user =
                                                Provider.of<Userr?>(context,
                                                    listen: false);
                                                var postDocRef =
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                    .collection('myOrders')
                                                    .doc(user?.uid)
                                                    .collection('items')
                                                    .doc();
                                                Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false).updatecartdata(
                                                    context,
                                                    {
                                                      'value': documentSnapshot['value'] + 0.5,
                                                      'price': documentSnapshot['price'] + (documentSnapshot['ogprice'] / 2),
                                                    },id
                                                );
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('+'),
                                            ),
                                          ]),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              _BillDetailView(),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class _BillDetailView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textStyle =
    Theme
        .of(context)
        .textTheme
        .bodyText1!
        .copyWith(fontSize: 16.0);

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Bill Details',
            style:
            Theme
                .of(context)
                .textTheme
                .headline6!
                .copyWith(fontSize: 17.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false)
                .getTotalCost(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Item total', style: textStyle),
                    Text('${snapshot.data}', style: textStyle),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}");
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Calculation.dart

```
  Future<dynamic> getTotalCost(BuildContext context) async {
    final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context, listen: false);
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('myOrders')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('items')
        .get();
    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      totalCost += doc["price"];
    }
    print(totalCost.toString());
    return totalCost.toString();
  }
```

The value in the front end changes but last updated(Added or subtracted) value is not reflecting.After hot reload it changes, but not automatically.
How to change this code to automatically update the item total in the front end.

Comment: Use StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder.

Comment: what change I need to make in Calculation.dart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder` to get live updates.

Changes your `Calculation.dart` to:

```
Stream<dynamic> getTotalCost(BuildContext context) async {
    final user = Provider.of<Userr?>(context, listen: false);
    double totalCost = 0.0;
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('myOrders')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('items')
        .snapshots();

    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
      totalCost += doc["price"];
    }
    
    print(totalCost.toString());
    return totalCost.toString();
  }
```

And change `FutureBuilder` to `StreamBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: Provider.of<Calculations>(context, listen: false)
                .getTotalCost(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Item total', style: textStyle),
                    Text('${snapshot.data}', style: textStyle),
                  ],
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}");
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
```